# SQL Server sequential query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To My understanding, SQL Server executes query sequentialy
In the below Query, If Query 3 takes 20 Sec to finish, *Will sql server wait at that point for the SP to finish execution to progress to Query 4*

```
Update...   -- Query 1

Insert...   -- Query 2

EXCE spMySP -- Query 3

Update..    -- Query 4
```

Comment: Yes.  SQL Server executes steps one at a time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , So, can I write Query 4 , assuming that Query 3 is over

Comment: Yes. But if two people log in and run this simultaneously and you haven't coded for it you might run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, `Sql Server` will wait until your Previous query is executed. as Gordin say `Sql Server` takes one request at a time from same server. so it will execute query by their order.
You actually can only execute a single statement per batch with `SQL Server` Compact

Answer (score -1):

no because sql is query-proccessed-thread. So it won't wait, it process one by one